# In Java, if I call a class that extends Thread from another runnable object, which Thread executes?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I am working on some concurrency programming and one part is bothering me.

Let's say I have some class `Foo` that extends Thread and implements it's own public method called `bar()` as well as the required `run()` method. If I implement multiple `Foo` objects, each one containing a reference to another `Foo` object, and inside the `run()` method for the `Foo` class is a call on the `bar()` method for whatever `Foo` object it has a reference to. If the `Foo` object with name "`Thread-1`" calls `bar()` on the `Foo` object with name "`Thread-2`", then who is actually executing the method code in "`Thread-2`"?
Does execution get handed off from "`Thread-1`" to "`Thread-2`" to execute or does "`Thread-1`" continue executing code in "`Thread-2`"? If it is the second choice, how can I make it act like the first choice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A new thread is started only if you invoke `thread.start()` (or use `executor.submit(runnable)`). All other method invocations remain in the current thread.

Comment: I meant once the other threads are running, is there a way to make a call from one thread to another, but have the callee thread execute the code instead of the caller thread?

Comment: @grg-n-sox - not possible by definition - you cannot call a thread, only signal it.  About the nearest you can get is to queue an object or proxy or something to the other thread an Wait() on it.  The target thread could do some work on the object and Notify() it.

Answer (score 0):

`Foo` is just an object, imagine it does not extends `Thread`, what would you expect? As long as new thread is not `start()`ed, you are just calling an ordinary method, on behalf of the calling thread.

Moreover, if calling a method on a different `Thread` object would cause that thread taking over the execution, what would happen with the current thread's execution?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from being executed when you start the thread, `run()` is a normal method. If you manuallly call, it behaves like any other method, meaning it is executed inside the caller's thread.

Answer (score 0):

It will run on the thread that called it.  Calling a method in a class that extends thread is no different than calling a method of any other class.

```
public class A extends Thread
{
     public void bar()
     {
         System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
     }

     public void run()
     {
         new A().bar();
     }

     public static void main()
     {
         A testA = new A();     
         testA.setName("parent");
         testA.start();        
     }
}
```

Should print 'parent';